# Bug in anonymous function for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop, anonymous-function

```
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

// var future_value;

var calculateFV = function (investment, interest, years) { 
    var future_value = investment;
     for (var i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
       future_value = future_value + (future_value * interest / 100);
     }
     future_value = future_value.toFixed(2);
     return future_value;
     //$("future_value").value = calculateFV(investment, interest, years);
};

var processEntries = function () {
    var investment = parseFloat($("investment").value);
    var interest = parseFloat($("interest").value);
    var years = parseFloat($("years").value);

    $("future_value").value = calculateFV(investment, interest, years);
};

window.onload = function () {
    $("calculate").onclick = processEntries;
};
```

I think the problem is with the for loop but I don't know, I've tried everything at this point. Nothing will run, maybe you guys can spot the bug?

```
<label for="investment">Total Investment:</label>
        <input type="text" id="investment">
        <span id="investment_error">&nbsp;</span><br>

        <label for="rate">Annual Interest Rate:</label>
        <input type="text" id="annual_rate">
        <span id="rate_error">&nbsp;</span><br>

        <label for="years">Number of Years:</label>
        <input type="text" id="years">
        <span id="years_error">&nbsp;</span><br>

        <label for="future_value">Future Value:</label>
        <input type="text" id="future_value" disabled><br>

        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><br>
```

Thinking now that it's something to do in my HTML?

Comment: What's the bug you are talking about ? What is the expected behavior ?

Comment: "_the problem_"? What is the problem?

Comment: Where's the anonymous function?

Comment: It's suppose to take in the value of the 3 textboxes and return future value in the forth as output

Comment: Yes, but what happens instead? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Just checked the console and I have two errors saying "TypeError: $(...) is null"

Comment: It means that some of those ids don't exist. You'll have to show the HTML as well.

Comment: Okay I just added it to my post

Comment: You don't have any element with the id "interest".

Comment: annual_rate is the interest, i renamed the interest var in the parameter as annual_rate, but it still isn't working

Comment: You need to change the `$("interest")` part, not the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work with one minor correction, `$("interest").value` should be `$("annual_rate").value` to work with your HTML:

The only thing I would change is to remove the `disabled` property on the  `future_value` input. With the `diasbled` attribute on, the value will not be submitted. You can use `readonly` to prevent users from modifying the field. However you should double check the calculations on the back end in any case.

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

// var future_value;

var calculateFV = function(investment, interest, years) {
  var future_value = investment;
  for (var i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
    future_value = future_value + (future_value * interest / 100);
  }
  future_value = future_value.toFixed(2);
  return future_value;
  //$("future_value").value = calculateFV(investment, interest, years);
};

var processEntries = function() {
  var investment = parseFloat($("investment").value);
  var interest = parseFloat($("annual_rate").value);
  var years = parseFloat($("years").value);

  $("future_value").value = calculateFV(investment, interest, years);
};

window.onload = function() {
  $("calculate").onclick = processEntries;
};
```

```html
<label for="investment">Total Investment:</label>
<input type="text" id="investment">
<span id="investment_error">&nbsp;</span><br>

<label for="rate">Annual Interest Rate:</label>
<input type="text" id="annual_rate">
<span id="rate_error">&nbsp;</span><br>

<label for="years">Number of Years:</label>
<input type="text" id="years">
<span id="years_error">&nbsp;</span><br>

<label for="future_value">Future Value:</label>
<input type="text" id="future_value" readonly><br>

<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><br>
```

Answer (score -1):

Works fine. No problem.

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

//var future_value;

var calculateFV = function(investment, interest, years) {
  var future_value = investment;
  for (var i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
    future_value = future_value + (future_value * interest / 100);
  }
  future_value = future_value.toFixed(2);
  return future_value;
  //$("future_value").value = calculateFV(investment, interest, years);

};

var processEntries = function() {
  var investment = parseFloat($("investment").value);
  var interest = parseFloat($("interest").value);
  var years = parseFloat($("years").value);


  $("future_value").value = calculateFV(investment, interest, years);

};

window.onload = function() {
  $("calculate").onclick = processEntries;

};
```

```html
investment: <input id="investment" type="text" value="1000"><br/> 
interest: <input id="interest" type="text" value="8"><br/> 
years: <input id="years" type="text" value="2"><br/> 
future_value: <input id="future_value" type="text" value="" disabled><br/>

<input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
```